# mapping a many-to-many realtion transformed into a One-to-many relation

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, many-to-many, one-to-many, hibernate-mapping

I have a problem mapping 2 entity. I have the Entity **Azienda** and another **Sede**, one azienda can have many sedi and one sede can be related to many aziende.
I created a new relation table on the DB whit 2 foreign key as primary key (id_azienda,id_sede) and also a new entity **Owns** to convert the relation from Many-To-Many to One-To-Many for both sides.

This is how it looks when i don't put any data in the Own table:

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "nome": "Euronics",
        "capitale": 595959.0,
        "p_iva": "jbwiwb",
        "data_fondazione": "2019-11-14T23:00:00.000+0000",
        "owns": []
    }
```

In the table owns i put the id of the Azienda 1 and the id of the Sede 1. What i expect when i make the get all the Azienda call, is to see the azienda number 1 with the Sede number 1.

When i try to make a call from the Controller to get all the azienda the server give me an Error:

```
"message": "Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.example.demo.Azienda[\"owns\"])",
"path": "/azienda"
```

Here's the code:
**Azienda**

```
@Entity(name = "Azienda")
@Table(name = "azienda")
public class Azienda implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "nome")
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "capitale")
    private Double capitale;

    @Column(name = "p_iva")
    private String p_iva;

    @Column(name = "data_fondazione")
    private Date data_fondazione;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "azienda")
    private Set<Owns> owns;
    //---------------------------------------------------
```

**Sede**

```
@Entity(name="Sede")
@Table(name = "sede")
public class Sede implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //                 Colonne
    //----------------------------------------------------
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "nome")
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "citta")
    private String citta;

    @Column(name = "mq")
    private Double mq;

    @Column(name = "data_inserimento")
    private Date data_inserimento;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sede", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Owns> owns;

    //----------------------------------------------
```

**Owns**

```
@Entity(name = "Owns")
@Table(name = "owns")
public class Owns implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @EmbeddedId
    private OwnsKey id;

    //                 Colonne
    //----------------------------------------------------

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("id_azienda")
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_azienda")
    private Azienda azienda;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("id_sede")
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_sede")
    private Sede sede;

    //-----------------------------------------------------
```

And my DB is this:

```
create table azienda (
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    nome varchar(30) unique not null,
    capitale double,
    p_iva varchar(11) unique not null,
    data_fondazione date not null
);

create table sede (
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    nome varchar(30) unique not null,
    citta varchar(30) not null,
    mq double not null,
    data_inserimento date not null
);

create table owns (
    id_azienda int,
    id_sede int,
    foreign key (id_azienda) references azienda(id),
    foreign key (id_sede) references sede(id),
    primary key (id_azienda, id_sede)
);
```

Can someone explain me why it gaves me this error? :)

Comment: The error is caused, as the message indicates, by the fact that you have an infinite recursion between the entities, and that you thus can't transform that infinitely recursive structure to JSON: An Azienda has a collection of Owns. Each Own in the collection has an Azienda, which has a collection of Owns, which all have an Azienda, which has a collection of Owns, etc. etc. Don't return entities from your controller. Return objects which are carefully designed to be serialized as JSON, containing only and exactly the properties that you want to return.

Comment: Can you please show me an example? i'm a beginner and i'm still trying to understand a lot of things.

Comment: `class WhatYouReallyWantToReturnAsJson { private Long id; private String name; // getters, constructor omitted } [...] return new WhatYouReallyWantToReturnAsJson(azienda.getId(), azienda.getName());`

Comment: I created the class WhatYouReallyWantToReturnAsJson but i don't understand where i have to put the return new

Comment: You need to read my comment. The problem is that your Spring controller returns a recursive object. This recursive object needs to be transformed to JSON, but it can't, precisely because it's recursive. So, instead of returning a recursie object, your Spring controller should return a non-recursive object that can be transformed to JSON.